# Different value for every int variable

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a five int variables:

```
int firstSequence;
int secondSequence;
int thirdSequence;
int fourthSequence;
int fifthSequence;
```

Every of these variable could have value from 1-5. How to check in the most efficient way, if every of these variable has unique value? I mean only one can have value = 1 etc.

```
private bool IsOrderCorrect()
    {
        if(firstSequence != secondSequence && ...)
    }
```

Comment: Hint: Your solution would be easier if you used an array instead of 5 variables.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put them into an array then use `Distinct`:

```
new [] { 
         firstSequence, 
         secondSequence, 
         thirdSequence,
         fourthSequence, 
         fifthSequence 
       }.Distinct().Count() == 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
(  (1 << firstSequence)
 | (1 << secondSequence)
 | (1 << thirdSequence)
 | (1 << fourthSequence)
 | (1 << fifthSequence))
== (1 << 1) | (1 << 2) | (1 << 3) | (1 << 4) | (1 << 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
List<int> uniqueCheck = new List<int>() { firstSequence, secondSequence, thirdSequence, fourthSequence, fifthSequence };

if(uniqueCheck.Distinct().Count() == uniqueCheck.Count())
{
   //they are unique
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the most efficient way.

The most efficient way would be to sum them and make sure the sum equals 15.

Testing this on my machine a 1000000 times results in the .Distinct().Count() == 5 method taking 244.77 milliseconds.

Doing the same thing but using .Sum() == 15 takes 54.92 so the sum method is more efficient.

Having said this, using Distinct().Count(), will generalise to more cases however the op asked for the most efficient way.

EDIT:

Sorry, I was rushing when I typed the original so it was flawed. My general method remains the same but instead of summing the numbers, you should sum the squares, which I believe should equal 55 and should only sum to 55 if the numbers are distint.

Testing with the sum of squares takes 139 milliseconds which is still faster than .Distinct().Count() == 5

So my answer should be updated to .Select(x => x*x).Sum() == 55

Comment: If the values are 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, they also sum to 15.

Comment: trying Falk Hüffner's answer above takes 6 milliseconds to calculate 1000000 times, which is faster than .Distinct().Count() and .Sum()

Answer (score -3):

If they were in an array it would be very easy

```
        int[] numbers = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j!= i && j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) {
                    // you know what to do
                }
            }
        }
```